# Special alignment about split environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I have some trouble in formatting my formula, so far I am able to get it look like this:

[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

Here is my MWE I am using `split`, I don't think I can use `align` because it will break my formulas into smaller ones.

```
\begingroup
\everymath{\scriptstyle}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split} 
&\forall \boldsymbol{value_{1}}, \boldsymbol{value_{2}}, \boldsymbol{value_{3}}     \textsf{Relationship(}\boldsymbol{value_{1}},\boldsymbol{value_{2}},\boldsymbol{value_{3}}\textsf{)} \to \\
&    \textsf{Unary(}\boldsymbol{value_{1}},\boldsymbol{value_{2}},\boldsymbol{value_{3}}\textsf{)} \vee \\
&    \textsf{Binary(}\boldsymbol{value_{1}},\boldsymbol{value_{2}},\boldsymbol{value_{3}}\textsf{)} \vee \\
&    \textsf{Ternary(}\boldsymbol{value_{1}},\boldsymbol{value_{2}},\boldsymbol{value_{3}}\textsf{)}
\end{split} 
\end{equation}
\endgroup
```

Comment: You *can* just insert `\quad` or `\qquad` for lines 2-3. Are you open to better suggestions in terms of your display? In particular, I don't really like the `\boldsymbol{<text>}` approach.

Comment: That is not a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @Werner, sure how can I do better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\val}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\func}[1]{\textsf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\forall \val{value}_{1}, \val{value}_{2}, \val{value}_{3}
  \quad
  \func{Relationship}(\val{value}_{1},\val{value}_{2},\val{value}_{3}) \to \\
&\qquad \func{Unary}(\val{value}_{1},\val{value}_{2},\val{value}_{3}) \vee {}\\
&\qquad \func{Binary}(\val{value}_{1},\val{value}_{2},\val{value}_{3}) \vee {}\\
&\qquad \func{Ternary}(\val{value}_{1},\val{value}_{2},\val{value}_{3})
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comments.

1. You definitely don't want `\everymath{\scriptstyle}`.
2. `\boldsymbol{value_1}` is wrong. You should use text commands as shown and the subscript shouldn't be bold
3. The parentheses should not be from the sans serif font, but from the math font.
4. `{}` after `\vee` makes for correct spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Split environment allow to put ampersand anywhere in aporpriate place in text, so the solution given by `egreg`can be rewrite also into:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\val}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\func}[1]{\textsf{#1}}

    \begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\forall \val{valu}      % this value is split into two parts ...
    &\!                 %  by \! is reduced space before second par of splitted \val{...}
        \val{e}_{1},    % rest of first line of given expression
        \val{value}_{2}, \val{value}_{3}
        \quad\func{Relationship}(\val{value}_{1}, \val{value}_{2},\val{value}_{3}) to\\
    &   \func{Unary}(\val{value}_{1},\val{value}_{2},\val{value}_{3}) \vee {}\\
    &   \func{Binary}(\val{value}_{1},\val{value}_{2},\val{value}_{3}) \vee {}\\
    &   \func{Ternary}(\val{value}_{1},\val{value}_{2},\val{value}_{3})
\end{split}
\end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

Final result is almost the same, as in `egreg` example. With moving of & in the firs line, you can adjust the start of others lines.